# D6 Is it possible to set node reference field and use this value in another field on the same node/add form?

Tags: 6, ajax, nodes, tokens

I have two node reference fields in a Content Type.
Driver
Manager

Each driver belongs to a certain organisational unit. Every organisational unit has a set of managers. I need the organisational unit to retrieve the right selection of managers in the node reference field Manager.

Now I need to select the driver, save the node and edit the node again. Then I can select the manager from the right set of managers (based on the organisational unit token I supply in the node reference field).

Is there any other way I can do this without implementing a 2-step form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two modules are intended for that purpose and have D6 versions.  I think Dependent Fields sounds closer to what you want, but Hierarchical Select Node Reference may work almost as well.

[Dependent Fields](http://drupal.org/project/dependent_fields)

> The Dependent Fields module (formerly AHAH Dependent Fields) allows cck based fields to specify another field as a controller field, and react to its changes on the form using AHAH/AJAX without the form re-loading.

[Hierarchical Select Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/hs_nodereference)

> This module allows the use of Hierarchical Select form element as a widget for CCK node reference field, both in node add/edit form and in views filter.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had a look at the Conditional Fields (http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module before and I thought this wasn't what I was looking for. I missed out on the Dependent Fields module. Thanks!